# How do I make a SPARQL query to find the highest value for a property?

Tags: database, rdf, sparql

Lets say I have a predicate like 'age' where the values of all age triples are integer literals. What SPARQL query would return the subject with the highest age in the data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to do `order by desc` with the age predicate and then `limit` to just get the first one.

```
PREFIX ns:    <http://namespace.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?s ?age
WHERE { ?s ns:age ?age }
ORDER BY DESC(?age) LIMIT 1
```

See the semantics of `order by` in SPARQL [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#modOrderBy)

With the next version of SPARQL , 1.1, that is already supported in some systems you can use function aggregates and do ..

```
SELECT (max(?age) as ?maxage)
WHERE { ?s ns:age ?age }
```

This is not supported in all triple stores currently.

Comment: thanks, I was hoping there was a better way than just limiting the results from a more general query but I guess I'll have to wait until 1.1. for that :)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Manuel's queries you may need to use `xsd:integer` to force values to be cast to integer if your data has some invalid/dodgy values:

```
PREFIX ns:    <http://namespace.org/ontology/>
PREFIX xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
SELECT ?s ?age
WHERE { ?s ns:age ?age }
ORDER BY DESC(xsd:integer(?age)) LIMIT 1
```

Depending on your data you may need to add this into his second SPARQL 1.1 query as well.